# install4j RPM installer does not set release and license

Tags: install4j

The install4j RPM installer should set release and license. Otherwise it's not a valid RPM package. Should be also nice if one could set the description.

Comment: Cool. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Please provide feedback to support@ej-technologies.com. Stackoverflow is really just for questions.

Comment: These options are available in spec files and in several other tools as far as I know. I thought that there was a "release" attribute in its Ant task. If it doesn't work, it's clearly a bug.

Comment: @gouessej: That's right. Install4j produces a 'somehow' valid RPM package as it can be installed using rpm -i, but can't be put into a repository as YUM/DNF require a valid license/release field in the package.